# Pass listOf(mapOf(x,y,z)) as parameter in Kotlin

Tags: parameters, kotlin

Very new to Kotlin and working on a problem that requires me to take these values as a parameters for a function

```
(
    starting = "begin",
    target = "end",
    edges =
    listOf(
        mapOf("start" to "x", "end" to "y", "distance" to 25)
    )
}
```

Ive got the first two fine but the list of maps is confusing me.

```
a(starting: String, target: String, edges: ListOf(mapOf(x,y,z)){}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare `edges` parameter as

```
edges: List<Map<String, Any>>
```

The first type parameter of the map is type of keys, and the second is type of values in that map.

`Any` as the type of map values is required because you're mixing ints and strings as values.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.